# Can I create my own query in wordpress with traditional methods?

Tags: query, tags

I am new to developing themes with wordpress, so here's my question. Can I create my own query in wordpress with traditional methods?

I know we use the WP query methods, but what is the most efficient way, and can I use my own SQL commands to generate a query for all tags with published post? for example.

I am using get_the_tags() with wordpress, but it is only providing the tags related to the post. I want all tags with published post to display. And come to think about it now, I think it isn't even displaying the tags, just the post category, so I must be doing something wrong.

Below is the code in the functions.php file

```
 function get_all_tags(){
    $posttags = get_the_tags('');
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$tag->name.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

In the single.php file, i am calling on this function.

```
<?php $tagsAll = get_all_tags(); echo $tagsAll; ?>
```

I picked up some of this from online searches, but I am trying to modify for all tags with little success. Thanks

Comment: Use [`get_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tags/). You should almost never need to use manual SQL queries.

Comment: I agree with Jacob.  You could use SQL, but there is no need.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up fellas, I did make a small change based on your recommendations @JacobPeattie and now I can see all the tags in the list. I wish I could give you both a vote but, I guess I don't have enough reputation score to do so. One quick question for both of you , in the get_tags() link provided, 

I see this code: get_tags( string|array $args = '' ): WP_Term[]|int|WP_Error

Is it necessary to use a variable like $args as an option, or can I just use the empty apostrophes on their own, without the variable to store it in? Does that change the purpose in any way?

Comment: I have this other question that hasn't been answered, maybe you guys can point me in the right direction. Thanks again for your assistance. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416964/how-can-i-get-the-next-post-link-to-go-beyond-the-1st-2-post-in-the-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some assistance from @JacobPeattie I modified the code to the recommended get_tags() function. Now in the functions.php I have the following code.

```
// Get al the tags with published post
function get_all_tags(){
    $posttags = get_tags('');
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$tag->name.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

In the single.php file, I call this with the following code.

```
<?php $tagsAll = get_all_tags(); echo $tagsAll; ?>
```